# Prove that $E(F(X))=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_x[P(X=x)]^2$

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, expected-value

Suppose $X$ is a random variable with CDF $F$. Prove that $$E(F(X))=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_x[P(X=x)]^2$$

It was straightforward to prove that $E(F(X))=\frac{1}{2}$ for a continuous random variable:
\begin{align}
E(F(X))&=\int_\mathbb{R} F(x)F(dx)\\
&=\int_\mathbb{R}\int_{-\infty}^xF(dt)F(dx)\\
&=\int_\mathbb{R}\int_t^\infty F(dx)F(dt)\quad\text{(Fubini's thm)}\\
&=\int_\mathbb{R}(1-F(t))F(dt)\\
&=1-\int_\mathbb{R}F(t)F(dt)
\end{align}
which, gives us $E(F(X))=1/2$. However, I must have used the continuity condition somewhere in the proof that I need to not use for the general proof but I can't figure where. How should the general proof go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For general measures you cannot write integral from $t$ to $\infty$ etc. You have to say whether $t$ is included or not. Here is the correct argument:

\begin{align}
E(F(X))&=\int_\mathbb{R} F(x)F(dx)\\
&=\int_\mathbb{R}\int_{(-\infty,x]}F(dt)F(dx)\\
&=\int_\mathbb{R}\int_{[t,\infty)} F(dx)F(dt)\quad\text{(Fubini's thm)}\\
&=\int_\mathbb{R}(1-F(t-))F(dt)\\
&=1-\int_\mathbb{R}F(t)F(dt)+\sum [P(X=t)]^{2}
\end{align} by writing $F(t-)$ as $F(t)-(F(t)-F(t-))$ and noting that $F(t)-(F(t)-F(t-))=0$ except for the at-most countable number of points $t$ where $P(X=t)>0$.